# Tabbed Image Browser for Windows

Tags: windows, images, image-processing, image-viewer

I'm looking for image browsers/photo managers in the same vein as:

- Picasa
- XnView MP
- Faststone Image Viewer

but with support for multiple browser tabs (not just individual image viewer tabs)

Note: If possible, I'd the program to be just as light, fast and responsive with speedy thumbnail loading just like the examples I mentioned above. 
Especially important since my PC is pretty slow.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If your main feature is browser tabs, why not a multi-tabbed file explorer like Q-Dir?

Answer (score 1):

I've been on a quest for a similar application.
Other than XNViewMP, I've been having a hard time finding any image viewers capable of having multiple images open with a tabbed interface.

My options so far are [Nomacs](https://nomacs.org/), a free and open source image viewer that is available as a portable app as well.

It seems to be relatively lightweight and fast to open, highly configurable keyboard and mouse behavior, it can open multiple tabs each with independent folder tree and thumbnail view.

Downsides are it can't open HDR file formats, and a few quirks with tab focus and always using windows rather than tabs to open new images.

Also [FreeVimager](https://www.contaware.com/freevimager.html), though it has tabs, I'm not sure multiple folder browsers are supported.

Downsides being it also doesn't support HDR formats, and the dated looks, if that matters to you.